# Tabcontrol con html y javascript

Tags: javascript, html, .net

pongo este ejemplo como refencia tengo en .net datos con una grilla el cual paso como parametro un registro a un textbox al seleccionar una fila , y se actualiza mi pagina quedando como seleccionada la primera como puedo omitir eso.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

/* Style the close button */
.topright {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.topright:hover {color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">&times</span>
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminando la línea:

`document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();`

En esta sentencia, `document.getElementById("defaultOpen")`, obtiene el elemento con `id="defaultOpen"` que si te fijas en tu html es precisamente

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
```

La función `click()` simula un click de ratón que es lo que hace que se quede seleccionada